# Sanity checks between hive and a database

Tags: mysql, bash, for-loop, hive

Currently I have a bash script that does a basic row count to a hive table (stores result in a variable), then another row count to a mysql table. Bash then evaluates the 2 variables. No problems here so far.

There is anotherScript.sh in which has listed about 50 table names.
eg. target_tables=" name_table1
name_table2
name_table3
... and so on.

I'd imagine this would need a for loop to automate the above script to run through all the 50 tables in a single command? How do I tell my script to pick out the table names from anotherScript.sh?

Comment: Mind showing us the contents of anotherScript.sh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To loop through the variable, you can have:

```
for table in $target_tables; do
    (do something with $table)
done
```

If your table names contain spaces, use `IFS=$'\n'`:

```
(
    IFS=$'\n'
    for table in $target_tables; do
        (do something with $table)
    done
)
```

If you're using bash 4.0+ the safest would be:

```
readarray -t tables <<< "$target_tables"
for table in "${tables[@]}"; do
    (do something with $table)
done
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I used the readarray as my choice. Works great!